# JSONObject error parsing JSON containing javascript

Tags: json, org.json

I have some JSON that contains the following:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                if ( this.y == 0) {
                    return ('N/A');
                } else {
                    return (this.y) + '%';
                };
            }
        }
    }
},
```

JSONLint.com parses this and says its fine. JSFiddle runs OK and the result is correct.  However, using an application that uses the org.json library it throws an error.

It doesn't matter what the javascript code is - whatever it is, it throws an error - even though its legal JSON.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Because it is not [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: Please add a screenshot from JSONLint validation.

Comment: In prepping the code for stackoverflow I also removed the double-quotes.   Going back to JSONLint and inserting double quotes around everything: keywords AND the function defs, it did validate in JSONLint.  

So now I'm wondering why/how JSFiddle accepts the JSON without the double-quoted function defs, but org.json does NOT accept it?